# Does the word "exgest" exist?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage, antonyms

A colleague of mine found reference to the word ***"Exgest"*** in a contract. In context, this appeared to mean the opposite of the word ***"Ingest"*** which was used earlier in the contract. These words were intended to convey the consumption and processing of data in a system.

Does this word, ***"Exgest"***, actually exist, and what does it mean?

**Edit:**
List of prior research:
[google: exgest](https://www.google.com/#q=exgest)
[google: word definition exgest](https://www.google.com/#q=word+definition+exgest)
[google: site:dictionary.com exgest](https://www.google.com/#q=site:dictionary.com+exgest)
[reverse lookup: opposite of ingest](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=opposite+of+ingest)
[merriam webster search: exgest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exgest)
[dictionary.com exgest](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exgest?s=t)
 
[english.stackexchange.com search](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=exgest)

Comment: Well, it exists (or did at one time) as a cold medication.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper antonym of ingest is ***egest*** not *exgest*. Etymologically *e-*
 serves the same purpose as *ex-*.

[***egest***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egestion)

> To discharge or excrete from the body.

Comment: So then the word "exgest" does not exist?

Comment: No it doesn't. e- and ex- prefixes are similar variants and egestion sounds better and is less complicated than exgestion.

Comment: Actually it does exist, but it's a proper noun. It's the trade name of a medication. Egest is 100% correct, I'm just pointing out that [Exgest](http://www.drugs.com/mtm/exgest-la.html) is technically a word, but not in the sense of your question

Comment: ‘Exgest’ would be akin to having ‘absduct’ instead of ‘abduct’. The extra s is only used before certain consonants in Latin. In modern words coined by people who don’t know Latin properly, anything goes, as the name of the medication shows.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, _Au contraire_, for trademark purposes something that's easy to remember and to pronounce, but _not_ a word is a good medicine name.

Comment: I never said it wasn't—just that it doesn't adhere to the morphophonological rules of Latin, even though it is (pseudo-)Latin.

Comment: I would avoid *egest* because it seems to be very uncommon and the meaning might not be totally clear. E.g. [here](https://blog.bigml.com/2012/11/12/digesting-big-data/), *egestion* is used in a different sense: "getting rid of the unwanted, unclean, unnecessary parts of your data".

Comment: Exactly, the problem with ESL learning is that just because a word is in the dictionary, doesn't mean we should be encouraging people to learn it. The purpose of language is to communicate and if a word doesn't appear in the top 20k lemmas, then chances are poor that the person you are speaking to knows it either.

Comment: In the list of top 100k english words by frequency, "egress" is at line 38k and "export" is at 14.8k. "egest" doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 10):

There are also another two similar terms applicable for data flows:

**ingress** and **egress**

Comment: Although the term "data ingestion" seems to be more common than "data ingress" (and "data egress" is virtually not used at all), I like the matching pair of "ingress" and "egress".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **data import** and **data export**.

Plain and simple and everyone immediately understands the meaning. (This advantage should not be underestimated, especially when non-native speakers are involved who also might not be familiar with latin.)

(For a discussion of further options, see e.g.: https://blog.greglow.com/2019/06/04/opinion-data-ingestion-and-opposites/)

Comment: I totally agree, practically, in a business context, to use as simple and explanatory words as possible. My original question was an etymological one however, so the accepted answer stands, however I will give you some rep for your great answer.